# has one relationships and deletion in grails

Tags: grails, one-to-one

How should I delete the child object in a hasOne relationship in grails
for e.g.:

```
class Face {
 static hasOne = [nose: Nose]
}
class Nose {
 Face face
 static belongsTo= Face
}
```

I tried deleting the child object by two ways

```
1. face.nose.delete()
2. nose.delete()
```

I always get the same exception Deleted object resaved by cascade in both the ways. And one more do I have any dynamic methods (like addTo and removeFrom for hasMany) for hasOne?
Any help?

Comment: Have you tried setting face.nose = null;

Comment: Yes did that too. But it is of no use..still i get the same exception

Comment: Do you really need `static belongsTo= Face`?

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
face.nose = null
face.save()
nose.delete()
```

If you only delete nose then the property face.nose is still set. A later call of face.save() would resave the nose.

If you only set face.nose = null (without saving) then the change isn't saved to the database. A later query to the database to get a Face would give you a Face with the nose set and a save() would resave it.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your class as follows:

```
class Face {
        Nose nose
}

class Nose {    
        static belongsTo = Face
}
```

Then to delete try:

```
def f = Face.get(1)
f.nose.delete()
f.delete()
```

Comment: I think the Face should not be deleted only the Nose.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
noseId = face.nose.id
face.nose = null
nose.get(noseId).delete(flush:true)
```